# Safari error overflow-x hidden scrollbar bug

Tags: html, css, safari

I have following table:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>TTT</title>
    <style>
    /* on both */
   body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.full-width {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 -9999rem;
  padding: .25rem 9999rem;
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.125rem;
}

    </style>
</head>

<body>
        <table class="full-width" style="background-color: #000;">
            <td style="color: #FFF">
                   Text
             </td>
             <td style="color: #FFF">
                   Text 2   
             </td>
         </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Setting html overflow-x: hidden is not an option. Would work but destroy my outbound table. Only on Safari I've a scrollbar. And here.

Snippet partly from here: https://css-tricks.com/full-browser-width-bars/

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: Well, I would like to deny vertical scrolling on Safari. It's a browser dependant problem.